# Is there a way to have a function in my bash script auto run on any command error?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, error-handling

I'm writing a shell script that needs to do a bunch of commands and every command depends on every previous command. If any command fails the entire script should fail and I call an exit function. I could check the exit code of each command but I am wondering if there is mode I can enable or a way to get bash to do that automatically.

For example, take these commands:

```
cd foo || myfunc
rm a || myfunc
cd bar || myfunc
rm b || myfunc
```

Is there a way where I can somehow signal to the shell before executing these commands that it should call myfunc if any of them fail, so that instead I can write something cleaner like:

```
cd foo
rm a
cd bar
rm b
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use bash [trap ERR](http://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling#Set_ERR_trap_to_exit) to make your script quit if any command returns status greater than zero and execute your function on exiting.

Something like:

```
myfunc() {
  echo 'Error raised. Exiting!'
}

trap 'myfunc' ERR

# file does not exist, causing error
ls asd
echo 123
```

Note that [bash trap](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) `ERR` does implicit `set -o errexit` or `set -e` and is not POSIX.

And the `ERR` trap is not executed if the failed command is part of the command list immediately following `until` or `while` keyword, part of the test following the `if` or `elif` reserved words, part of a command executed in `&&` or `||` list, or if the command’s return status is being inverted using `!`.

Answer (score 3):

A (perhaps) simpler variation on the accepted answer:

1. Use `set -e`
   to cause the failure of one command to abort the execution of a list.
2. Simply list your commands.
3. Use an `if`-`then`-`else` statement
   to execute your error-handling command(s). 
   This last piece is a bit tricky. 
   Watch:

```
set -e
if
    cmd1                        # e.g.,     cd foo
    cmd2                        # e.g.,     rm a
    cmd3                        # e.g.,     cd bar
    cmd4                        # e.g.,     rm b
then
    set +e
    commands to do upon success (if any)
else
    set +e
    myfunc
    other commands to do upon failure (if any)
fi
```

The tricky part is that you put your commands
*into **the `if` part*** of the `if`-`then`-`else`,
not the `then` part or the `else` part. 
Recall that [the syntax of the `if` statement](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07) is

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
   ↑↑↑↑
```

The `set -e` tells the shell that,
if `cmd1` (`cd foo`) fails,
it should not go on and execute `cmd2`
(`rm a`),
and so on down the line. 
If this happened to a command at the outermost level of a shell script,
the shell would exit. 
However, since the `cmd1` · `cmd2` · `cmd3` · `cmd4`
is a (compound) list following an **`if`**,
the failure of any of those four commands
simply causes the entire list to fail —
which causes the `else` clause to be executed. 
If all four commands succeed, the `then` clause is executed.

In either case, the first thing you should do is probably to disable
(turn off) the `e` option by doing `set +e`.
Otherwise, the script might get blown out of the water
if a command in `myfunc` fails.

`set -e` is [specified and described in the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set).

Comment: This answer is wrong. From the POSIX spec linked in this post: _The -e setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the while, until, if, or elif reserved word, a pipeline beginning with the ! reserved word, or any command of an AND-OR list other than the last._

Answer (score 1):

Taken your word "*every command depends on every previous command. If any command fails the entire script should fail*" literally, i think you don't need any special function to treat the errors .

All you need is to chain your commands with `&&` operator and `||` operator, which does exactly what you wrote.

For example this chain will broke and will print "something went wrong" if **any** of the previous commands broke (bash reads from left to right)

```
cd foo && rm a && cd bar && rm b || echo "something went wrong"
```

Real example (i created dir foo, file a, dir bar and file b just for a real demo):

```
gv@debian:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests$ cd foo && rm a && cd bar && rm bb || echo "something is wrong"
rm: cannot remove 'bb': No such file or directory
something is wrong #mind the error in the last command

gv@debian:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests$ cd foo && rm aa && cd bar && rm b || echo "something is wrong"
rm: cannot remove 'aa': No such file or directory
something is wrong #mind the error in second command in the row
```

And finally if all commands have been executed successfully (exit code 0), script just goes on :

```
gv@debian:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests$ cd foo && rm a && cd bar && rm b || echo "something is wrong"
gv@debian:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/foo/bar$ 
# mind that the error message is not printed since all commands were successful.
```

What is important to remember is that with the use of && next command is executed if previous command exited with code 0 which for bash means success.

If any command goes wrong in the chain then the command / script / whatever follows || will be executed.

And just for the record, If you need to perform different actions depending on the command that broke , you could also do it with classic script by monitoring the value of `$?` which reports the exit code of the exactly previous command (returns zero if command executed successfully or other positive number if command failed)

Example:

```
for comm in {"cd foo","rm a","cd bbar","rm b"};do  #mind the error in third command
eval $comm
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];then 
        echo "something is wrong in command $comm"
        break
    else 
    echo "command $comm executed succesful"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
command cd foo executed succesfull
command rm a executed succesfull
bash: cd: bbar: No such file or directory
something is wrong in command cd bbar
```

Tip : You can suppress the message "bash: cd: bbar: No such file..." by applying `eval $comm 2>/dev/null`